# Determine if list is valid or not prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a program that checks if a list is valid or not valid. Here is what I have so far and I know it should be short I just cannot grasp my mind around prolog

These are my facts

```
pkg(pkg_name)
pkg(p1)
pkg(p2)
dpnd(p2,p1)
```

My rule is going to be `true_list()` 
this function will run as follows, if i select `true_list([p1,p2])` then it should return true, if i do `true_list([p1,p3,p2])` it should return false since p3 is not part of it. I have been looking at this for a while and feel like it should be so simple. I have tried this method

```
true_list(p1,p2):-package(package_name).
```

any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: One of your classmates asked the same question a little bit ago, but I guess they were feeling uncharitable and deleted it.

Comment: I've posted an answer based on your question, be sure to ask about anything you don't understand and I'll attempt to clarify it.

Comment: What's the role of the `dpnd/2` predicate? I suspect it's meant to express something like "if `dpnd(A, B)` and `A` is in the package list, then `B` must be in the package list as well". But this is just a guess. We cannot even begin to solve your problem *if you don't tell us what the problem is*. Please update the question adding more details about what is considered a correct solution.

Comment: Edit the question to add this information, please.

Comment: Isn't this basically `true_list(L) :- maplist(pkg, L)`?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie `dpnd/2` looks to be just another fact, probably for some other problem to be solved at some point. It really doesn't seem to do anything other than to describe the relation between packages. Whether to read that as "`p2` depends on `p1` to function" is not specified, but that would be my guess as to what it describes.

Comment: @G_V I asked about it above, and the OP confirmed that it was meant to capture these dependencies. They then removed that confirmation (which was between my two comments above).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to have a simple recursive predicate check every single element for existence.

for `?- true_list([p1,p2]).`

```
pkg(pkg_name).
pkg(p1).
pkg(p2).
dpnd(p2,p1).

%your input is a list of elements [Element1, Element2, Element3...ElementN]
true_list([]).
true_list([H|T]) :-  
  (pkg(H) ->  
    (true_list(T)) ; 
    (fail)
  ).
```

This code checks every element in your list to see if it exists as a fact `pkg` and fails if it finds an element that is NOT a `pkg`. It also succeeds with an empty list.

Comment: Not recursive *function*, but recursive *predicate*. This is Prolog. :)

Comment: `(goal_1 -> goal_2 ; !, fail)` is better expressed as `goal_1, goal_2`. If you absolutely need the cut (though it's better not to confuse people, including yourself, by feeling compelled to use it), it would be more efficient and still clearer to write it as `!, goal_1, goal_2` to *accept* the same lists.

Comment: Actually, `->` already eliminates the choice point. So `goal_1 -> goal_2 ; !, fail` is redundant. `!, goal_1 -> goal_2` would be sufficient. I think that is a little different than `!, goal_1, goal_2` since the latter would permit backtracking to `goal_1` if `goal_2` fails, but using `->` would not backtrack to `goal_1` in the event `goal_2` fails.

Comment: Thank you for the help with this! I was racking my brain trying to figure this one out. so correct me if I am wrong. You are creating an empty list with  `true_list([])`  then you have `true_list(H|T]) :- pkg(H)` which is saying if pkg(H) is the head `-> (true_list(t))` then true_list exists it the tail?  else fail.That part slightly confused me since I have never used the `->` operator. It is the if_then_else operator correct?

Comment: @Shazee You are not "creating an empty list" with `true_list([]).` What you are doing is declaring that `true_list(X)` is satisfied (succeeds) for an empty list `X = []`. Think declaratively with Prolog, not imperatively. Then the predicate `true_list([H|T])` describes what must be true for `true_list([H|T])` to succeed.

Comment: Edited the code to eliminate redundant calls, hopefully this makes it more understandable. @Shazee - Every list is a linked list, where each element references the next one in the list, and **all lists end in []**. This means that `functor([]).` is true if an empty list is passed to it in the call. The call `[H|T]` splits the list into the first element, and the remaining elements in `T`, where if there are no further elements, `T = []` and you have reached the end condition for the recursion.

Comment: @lurker Excellent observation, just to specify to avoid confusion, `->` eliminates the choice points **within** the [`if-then-else`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) construction according to the docs if I understood correctly. Its scope doesn't reach outside of it, so if I understand correctly choice points that exist before the `if` should still remain afterward, even within the same predicate call?